# Drag n Drop система

Tags: javascript, css

есть система Drag n Drop, система работает только для 1 слота, у каждого слота задан свой стиль, и вот как сделать, чтоб работало для каждого слота, чтоб картинка могла помещаться еще и в определенные слоты, а так же маленький вопрос, как добавить второй предмет, помимо clothes.png

```js
let select_item //Записываем в нее итем с которым работаем


let id_slot;
let currentDroppable = null;
let id_save_slot //Чтобы вернуть на прежнее место если отпустил не в div .cell

document.onmousedown = function(event) {

  select_item = event.target.closest('.item'); //Запоминаем итем который захватили

  let shiftX = event.clientX - select_item.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  let shiftY = event.clientY - select_item.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  select_item.style.position = 'absolute';
  select_item.style.zIndex = 1000;
  document.body.append(select_item);

  moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

  function moveAt(pageX, pageY) {
    select_item.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
    select_item.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
  }
  function onMouseMove(event) {
    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    select_item.hidden = true;
    let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    select_item.hidden = false;

    if (!elemBelow) return;

    let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.Rectangle_80');

    if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
      if (currentDroppable) { // null если мы были не над droppable до этого события
        // (например, над пустым пространством)
        leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
        id_save_slot = currentDroppable
      }
      currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
      if (currentDroppable) { // null если мы не над droppable сейчас, во время этого события
        // (например, только что покинули droppable)
        enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
      }
    }
    if (currentDroppable)  id_slot = currentDroppable;
    else id_slot = null //Если не в слоте div .cell -> далее вернет обратно
    console.log(id_slot)

  }



  function setItemSlot(item) {
    select_item.innerHTML = `<div class="item" id = "faa">`
      
     if(!item) { //Если нажали не в поле = возвращаем на место
        id_save_slot.innerHTML = `<div class="item"><img src="img/clothes.png" class="img" />
        <div class="name">Одежда</div></div>`
        return;
     }
     
     item.innerHTML = `<div class="item"><img src="img/clothes.png" class="img" />
     <div class="name">Одежда</div></div>`
  }
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  
  document.onmouseup = function(event) {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);

    //
    setItemSlot(id_slot); //Обрабатываем слот (передаем id_slot тот что запомнился при наводке в currentDroppable)
    leaveDroppable(id_slot)

    //
    select_item.onmouseup = null;
  };
};

function enterDroppable(elem) { //водим по слотам
  elem.style.background = 'white';
}

function leaveDroppable(elem) { //отпустили в слоте
  elem.style.background = '';
}

document.ondragstart = function() { //для плавного перемещения при захвате
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Уточните в чём проблема. Если вы смогли запрограммировать правильное поведение для одного слота, то в чём сложность применить это к любому количеству слотов?

Comment: В этом и проблема, код не мой, поэтому пытаюсь разобраться, и вот хочу спросить поэтому поводу как реализовать, не много не понятно.

Comment: Ну вот и напишите что именно непонятно. Что-то более конкретное. Если вообще код не понятен, то просто разберите каждую строчку, опишите для себя, что каждая строка делает, гуглите все незнакомые функции. Когда картина сложится, то либо появится конкретный вопрос, либо будет ясно, что надо делать.

Comment: Конкретно вопрос с этой функцией setItemSlot, как добавить еще один итем, чтоб было две разных img картинки.

Answer (score 0):

В программировании, если вы решили задачу для одного случая, нет никаких проблем решить её для любого количества таких же случаев. Надо просто поместить все специфичные детали в переменные и менять их по необходимости.

Вот упрощённый пример перетаскивания одного элемента в один слот:

```js
let item = document.querySelector('.item');
let slot = document.querySelector('.slot');
slot.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault())
slot.addEventListener('drop', () => {
  slot.appendChild(item);
});
```

```css
.slot {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px
}

.item {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Чтобы это работало для нескольких элеметов и слотов, надо менять значения переменной item и slot. Это можно делать по-разному, например так:

```js
let item;
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  items[i].addEventListener('dragstart', e => item = e.target);
}
document.addEventListener('dragover', e => e.preventDefault())
document.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  if (e.target.className == 'slot') {
    e.target.appendChild(item);
  }
});
```

```css
.slot {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px
}

.item {
  border: 1px dotted black;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
    <div class="slot"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" draggable="true"></div>
    <div class="item" draggable="true"></div>
    <div class="item" draggable="true"></div>
</div>
```

В вашем коде функция setItemSlot содержит HTML-код айтема. Чтобы функция могла использоваться для других айтемов, вам надо заменить этот html на переменную, значение которой менять в зависимости от того, какой айтем выбран.